# How to import image from filesystem url instead of /media/import?

Tags: import, product-images, csv

I am new to magento, I have around 8000 Products have to import them through CSV.. but the images are in the filesystem and the other user who has access to magento magento with limited permission doesn't have /media/import.. how to import them to magento... I am using latest version of magento

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that easily. You should somehow give the user access to /media/import/. Perhaps some kind of symlink will do the trick.